# Create secondary Archive page format?

Tags: ajax, archive-template

I'm trying to create a Ajax based category menu that reloads a section of the page with a couple posts from a specific categories based on the category menu item the user clicked.

Because my normal category archive pages show a 9 post grid and I just want this functionality to show 2, I was thinking the only way to accomplish this is to create some sort of alternate archive page that shows only 2 posts.

Is there a way to create a secondary archive page that each category will automatically render with?

For example, when I type in example.com/category then it'll show the default Archive page. I'm hoping for an alternate category page that will show up when I type in something like example.com/category-small or even example.com/category?count=2

If there's another way to accomplish the 2 post grid ajax menu I'm totally open to that as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could copy the contents of your current archive page file into a new file, then tweak the functionality there into what you need it to do. At the top of the file, give it a template name like this:

```
/*
  Template Name: Short Archive
 */
```

Now you can create a new page and select this template from the WordPress admin interface.

Comment: Would I then add a query string to pass in to generate the proper category?

Comment: That's one option; the other is to check which category is being requested and then give out either version. Something like if is_category($category = 'automobiles')... More info here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_category/